# What does observation mean in meta-analysis?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am performing some meta-analysis and I came around some paper which says " The results of a meta-analysis of 72 studies encompassing 33,732 observations... etc" or "We conducted a meta-analysis of 52 empirical studies representing 10,066 observations to test relationships" What does this observations mean in the context of meta-analysis.

The below table was given as an hint for my work from my advisor, although I could not understand what it does imply. How can I make observations with three factors in multiple ways?

[image: Example given]

The below table is the example I have been trying.
[![This is the example I have been doing][3]][3]

So comparing my work to the above given example I have two doubts.
1) 1 denotes presence and 0 denotes does not presence according to the 1st image.

2) Regarding sample size, its 175 for one study, and I read that in case I use the sample size for calculations as an estimate for the std err (i.e. precision) of the estimator (i.e. the effect size respective the correlation),I need to account for the fact, that the std error are not independent and I need to adjust the estimator for the precision of the estimator. 
If the sample size is 175 and you have 8 entries from the same study here database, so I have to devise the sample size by the number of entries... i.e 175/23 = 7.6

Answer (score 1):

The observation in the meta-analysis is the unit of the study.

For example in a medical meta-analysis an observation is a patient, so you can have 20 studies comprising 12000 observations (patients).

Comment: So you mean the observations are the patients or the observations made on that study?

Comment: I was making an example, in medicine your observations usually are patients. In a meta-analysis generally speaking the observation is the unit in the studied you are analyzing and this depends on the study you are considering, patients for medical ones, plants for study regarding plants...

Answer (score 1):

As stated by GGA, typically in an aggregate meta-analysis you have multiple units of analysis. Typically the study is the unit at hand, but it refers to smaller units (such as patients in a medical meta-analysis, or animals in a veterinary meta-analysis).

It is particularly important what the focus of your work will be. You typically want to tell people how to treat their individual patients, rather than how to conduct further trials (even if this is also meaningful).

According, the atomic unit / observation remains, for instance, the patient.

Assuming that your outcome of interest is the correlation, then the best approach is to use the sample size to compute the variances of the correlation coefficients, and then pool them using appropriate methods.

You can find here recommendations for these steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097453/how-to-compute-p-value-and-standard-error-from-correlation-analysis-of-rs-cor

https://www.meta-analysis.com/downloads/Meta-analysis%20Effect%20sizes%20based%20on%20correlations.pdf

Comment: Regarding the example its a sample help I got. Its random structure and I am confused how to enter data or the value of r into my table. Observation means size of the sample right?

Comment: Effect size is the correlation i.e r value. Correlation value is the effect size right?

Comment: I have edited my entry. The effect of interest might indeed be there as correlation factor. What is missing is a measure of precision / weighting factor (e.g. its standard error).

Comment: Once we have the effect sizes, how do we calculate the measure of precision or weighing factor?

Comment: I have edited the image, can you tell me. The effect size and size of the study are given. I am still stuck at entering values into my database. Like my only confusion is for the correlation values. How do I enter into the sheet? To make it simple I have totally 6 factors to be considered. So where should I enter each of the correlation value in the table is what I am confused about.

Comment: If you don't have the standard errors of the correlation coefficients (most likely your outcome of interest), then you have to back calculate them relying on the sample size. See edited version of my entry.

Comment: I am not sure what you need or want to do. Give me some additional context. Also clarify better what is the primary outcome, which are the secondary outcomes, and which are the moderators. You need a precision feature (eg standard error) for each unit of the analysis for the outcomes, but you may skip it for the moderators.

Comment: TF1, TF2, OF1, OF2, EF1 EF2 are my moderators. The primary outcome is to do hypothesis checking by these moderators. Like TF1 moderates the relationship between IT variables and IT Adoption. For calculating precision feature I have issue with sample size. As each paper has around 10 studies as I have multiple estimates from same study which are correlated. So how do I solve it is my question?

Comment: I still don't follow. Break down your goals into several simple steps. First identify 1 dependent variable, and then 1 independent variable. You need a precision estimate for the dependent variable as well (might be inverse of sample size, but the standard error of the dependent variable would be better). Then run this simple bivariate approach separately for all your potential moderators. If you want then to do meta-regression with multiple moderators simultaneously, you theorically can do it, but usually it is fraught with overfitting.

Comment: Okay. What are the best tools you can advise on to do it?

Comment: I recommend you to use the meta R package: metacont for continuous outcomes and metabin for dichotomous variables. You find plenty of examples here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/meta/meta.pdf.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. I have one last doubt, regarding missing values. How to replace missing values with mean? I mean I did google, but I got confused regarding it, so I am asking for some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have all the individual data from all the primary studies all you can do is to analyse the summary statistics which in your case seem to be correlations. The statements you see about studies having a total of X observations are intended to give the reader some background and are really redundant since the variability of the summary estimate from your meta-analysis already tells us about the precision with which you have estimated it. The table you show suggests that (a) your advisor wants you to do a meta-regression (you could I suppose always ask him/her) (b) you do not there have enough information to do even a simple meta-analysis as you do not have either the sample sizes for your r or some other measure of their variability. But perhaps you do have that and could not fit it in the table.

Comment: For example I have 10 studies and each of them have 100 as sample size so 10 * 100 is = 1000 is going to be the observations? So I can say based on 1000 observations ... Yes, I can ask him, but he is out of reach for now and I have work to do so I was asking for help. Yes, I should do a meta-regression. That was an idea he gave me to build. I do have them but I did not add them here. Its totally confusing.

Comment: The table above he gave was a hint and I have the data with me but I am getting confused how to take the data and fill in. The above one is just a sample.

Comment: You can say 1000 yes but that is the only part it plays in the analysis. If each study has 100 then you can use that to form the standard errors. You probably need to transform the r values to z using Fisher's hyperbolic arcsine transformation.

Comment: I have edited the image, can you tell me now. My only confusion is for the correlation values. To make it simple I have totally 6 factors to be considered. So where should I enter the correlation value for each of it in this table is my doubt.

Comment: Without knowing what software you are going to use I do not think anyone can help you here. Just as an extra comment I would have thought that trying to use six moderators simultaneously was rather ambitious.

Comment: I will be using SPSS for my work. Just a last doubt if you can help me. That's it and I am all clear. Just how to fill the correlation column is my doubt. Column 4 is my doubt.. Is it average of that column or what?

Comment: I am sorry but your attempts at clarifying things are not helping me here. Do I now understand that you have multiple estimates from the same study which are correlated? If so you have quite a different problem which I am not sure SPSS will deal with.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple estimates from same study which are correlated. Can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: I have not used SPSS for many years so I cannot tell you what to do as far as software is concerned I am afraid. It is certainly possible in R or Stata. What you want to do is fairly complicated and I would urge you to seek further training in advanced meta-analysis. A useful reference is    Nakagawa, S and Santos, E S A,
Methodological issues and advances in biological meta--analysis,
Evolutionary Ecology, 2012, 26, 1253-1274.
I think I got it from the author's ResearchGate page.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will look into it. Can you explain me a bit about replacing missing values with means?

Comment: That is really a separate issue from meta-analysis. Perhaps http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/MI.html will give you some clues or search this site for multiple imputation posts.

Comment: Thanks, that above material was really helpful and I could use them to solve my issue. I have studied regarding meta-analysis and I have one doubt which is confusing me. What is the difference between "Moderator" and "Sub-Groups". For example Countries, we can use it as sub-group as developing or developed country or use as moderator as dummy variable as 0,1. So, what is the exact difference here?

Comment: Using it as a moderator is superior to stratifying your data-set into two parts since it uses all the data to estimate the heterogeneity (assuming you are using random effects)

Comment: Well, thanks all these have helped me get an idea and reach to a point. Just one last and big doubt I have. "When studies in-cluded several IT or business value variables, and thus important relationships, the following procedure has been applied. If the difference between the variables were relevant for the later coding procedure, they have been added to the database as separate relationships. If the difference between the variables were not important, they have been arithmetically averaged". What does this mean? How that difference choice is made?

Comment: I think you may have to email the authors unless anyone else offers enlightenment